# SQL Statement to select row where previous row status = 'C' AS400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

This is being run on sql for IBMI Series 7

I have a table which stores info about orders. Each row has an order number (ON), part number(PN), and sequence number(SEQ). Each ON will have multiple PN's linked to them and each part number has multiple SEQ Number. Each sequence number represents the order in which to do work on the part. Somewhere else in the system once the part is at a location and ready to be worked on it shows a flag. What I want to do is get a list of orders for a location that have not yet arrived but have been closed out on the previous location( Which means the part is on it's way).

I have a query listed below that I believe should work but I get the following error: "The column qualifier or table t undefined". Where is my issue at?

```
Select * From (SELECT M2ON as Order__Number , M2SEQ as Sequence__Number,
M2PN as Product__Number,ML2OQ as Order__Quantity                    
FROM M2P 
WHERE M2pN in (select R1PN FROM R1P WHERE (RTWC = '7411') AND (R1SEQ = M2SEQ)
)                            
AND M2ON IN (SELECT M1ON FROM M1P WHERE ML1RCF = '')                                         
ORDER BY ML2OSM ASC) as T 
WHERE 
T.Order__Number in  (Select t3.m2on from (SELECT *
FROM(Select * from m2p
where m2on = t.Order__Number and m2pn = t.Product__Number
order by m2seq asc fetch first 2 rows only
)as t1 order by m2seq asc fetch first row only
) as t3 where t3.m2stat = 'C')
```

**EDIT- Answer for anyone else with this issue**
Clutton's Answer worked with slight modification so thank you to him for the fast response! I had to name my outer table and specify that in the subquery otherwise the as400 would kick back and tell me it couldn't find the columns. I also had to order by the sequence number descending so that I grabbed the highest record that was below the parameter(otherwise for example if my sequence number was 20 it could grab 5 even though 10 was available and should be shown first. Here is the subquery I now use. Please note the actual query names m2p as T1.

```
IFNULL((
    SELECT
        M2STAT
    FROM
        M2P as M2P_1
    WHERE
        M2ON = T1.M2ON
        AND M2SEQ < T1.M2SEQ
    AND M2PN IN (select R1PN FROM R1P WHERE (RTWC = @WC) AND (R1SEQ = T1.M2SEQ))
    ORDER BY M2SEQ DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
), 'NULL') as PRIOR_M2STAT
```

Comment: Can you write that without all the subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reading your question, it looks like something I do frequently to emulate RPG READPE op codes.  Is the key to M2P Order/Seq?  If so, here is a basic piece that may help you build out the rest of the query.

I am assuming that you are trying to get the prior record by key using SQL.  In RPG this would be like doing a READPE on the key for a file with Order/Seq key.

Here is an example using a subquery to get the status field of the prior record.

```
SELECT 
    M2ON, M2PN, M2OQ, M2STAT,
    IFNULL((
        SELECT
            M2STAT
        FROM
            M2P as M2P_1
        WHERE
            M2P_1.M2ON = M2ON
            AND M2P_1.M2SEQ < M2SEQ
        FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ), '') as PRIOR_M2STAT
FROM
    M2P
```

Note that this wraps the subquery in an `IFNULL` to handle the case where it is the first sequence number and no prior sequence exists.